# How to read contents of Excel sheet and storing it in a map with column1 as key, and the remaining columns as values

Tags: java, apache-poi

### I have an excel sheet which looks like this :

### Col_1 | Col_2|  Col_3 | Col_4

### A     | B    |  C     | D

### A1    | B1   |  C1    | D1

How to read this excel and store the values in a map with A as key, and B,C,D as values for that key.

Please find my codes below, which is not working as expected.

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                ArrayList<String> columnlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                List excelValues = new ArrayList();
                String key = StringUtils.EMPTY;


                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();                   
                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    if(row.getRowNum() > 0)
                    { 
                        if(cell.getColumnIndex()==0){

                            key = StringUtils.upperCase(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==1)
                        { 
                            tempPar = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            excelValues.add(tempPar);
                        }
                        if(tempPar.equalsIgnoreCase("Include")){

                         if(cell.getColumnIndex()==2)
                        { 
                            // Responsible for reading comma separated values from cell in excel sheet. 
                            StringTokenizer str= new StringTokenizer(cell.getStringCellValue(),COMMA);

                            while (str.hasMoreElements()) {
                                columnlist.add(StringUtils.upperCase(str.nextElement().toString()));
                            }
                            excelValues.add(columnlist.equals("") ? "" : columnlist);
                        }
                        else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==3){
                            ignorePK = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            ignorePK.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            excelValues.add(ignorePK);
                        }
                        }
                        map.put(key, excelValues);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written the code to read excel and store it to database using Apache Poi . You can refer it out and modify your own code.

```
 try {
             ExcelController ex = new ExcelController();
             File f1 = ex.convert(file);
             //     FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("E://Imp/Details.xlsx"));
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(f1);
             XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
             Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
             rowIterator.next();

             //    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
             for(int i=1;i<=51;i++){
                 Row row = rowIterator.next();
                 //For each row, iterate through each columns
                 Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                 while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                     Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                     //        System.out.println("cell.getStringCellValue().length() "+cell.getStringCellValue().length());
                     //   if( cell.getStringCellValue().length()>0){
                     List list = new ArrayList();
                     //       This will change all Cell Types to String
                     cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                     switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                             String bstring = "" + cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                             list.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                             System.out.println("boolean===>>>" + cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                             break;
                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                             String Nstring = "" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
                             list.add(Nstring);
                             break;
                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:


                             list.add(cell.getStringCellValue());


                             break;
                     }
//                   }else {
//                       break;
                     //        }


                 }
```

After you get the values over there just push it to the Map you have created.